# aggregate address on packet tracer

Tags: packet-tracer

I do have 3 networks 192.24.0.0/21 - 192.24.8.0/22 - 192.24.16.0/20 , I need to aggregate those addresses, I calculated the appropriate address which is 192.24.0.0/19 , now I want to simulate all that in packettracer, so I've configurated the 3 routers but I don't know how to configurate the one which take the aggregation address, I tried :

```
## first router ##
Cambridge(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0
Cambridge(config-if)#ip addr 192.24.7.1 255.255.248.0

## second router ##
Edimbourg(config)#dfinterface fastethernet 1/0
Edimbourg(config-if)#ip addr 192.24.11.1 255.255.252.0

## third router ##
Oxford(config)#interface FastEthernet1/1
Oxford(config-if)#ip address 192.24.31.1 255.255.240.0

## Main router ##
Router(config)#route bgp 1
Router(config-router)#aggregate-address 192.24.0.0 255.255.224.0
                      ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

but it generates an error on CLI 
[image]

Comment: Can you post the rest of your configuration? Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: I've edited commands and the picture of the entire example, thank you

Comment: What version of IOS are you running?

Comment: I don't think Packet Tracer supports that. It is sometimes pretty limited.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Packet tracer 7.0 doesn't appear to include the ability to summarize.  Here're the only commands available to me on any of the available routers in 7.0, including those running the simulated version of 15.x:

```
Router(config-router)#?
  bgp              BGP specific commands
  distance         Define an administrative distance
  exit             Exit from routing protocol configuration mode
  neighbor         Specify a neighbor router
  network          Specify a network to announce via BGP
  no               Negate a command or set its defaults
  redistribute     Redistribute information from another routing protocol
  synchronization  Perform IGP synchronization
  timers           Adjust routing timers
Router(config-router)#
```

Comment: are you saying that it can't be done on packet tracer ?